# Connect Subdomain to Subsystem in FW1

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, fw1

I have set up a subsystem in my app:

```
example.com/index.cfm/subsys:foo/bar
```

What I want to do is map a subdomain to that subsystem to eliminate the need for the subsystem specification in the PATH

```
subsys.example.com/index.cfm/foo/bar
```

We serve our FW1 app through IIS6 currently, but may migrate to Apache, so a solution in either is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Apache's [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) you can do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(subsys)\.example\.com
RewriteRule /index.cfm/(.*) /index.cfm/%1:$1
```

To make it work with multiple subdomains/subsystems, use a pipe-delimited list inside the parentheses:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sub1|sub2|sub3)\.example\.com
```

To make it work for *any* non-www subdomain, for any domain, use a condition such as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)\w+)\.
```

For IIS6, you would probably need third-party software, such as [Helicon Tech's ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com), which supports mod_rewrite syntax.

Comment: I've come across this solution, my only beef with it is that it's kind of static. What I mean by that is, you have to have the hostname in the definition. This makes it difficult to run across several domains (We have different domains bound for local development, staging and production)

Comment: However, if nothing else comes up, this might be what I'll end up going with

Comment: You don't _have_ to have the hostname there - you could adapt the first line to something like `^((?!www)\w+)\.` to make it work for any non-www subdomains.

Comment: Then would I be able to match the subdomain dynamically to a subsystem  as well? That sounds magical

Comment: Probably, but I'm not quite sure what you're asking there? The subdomain is linked by using a capturing group in the RewriteCond plus the %1 in the RewriteRule (as opposed to the regular $1 which is for captured groups from the rule itself).

Comment: Ok, that seems to answer it. Thanks a lot!